# Unique & repeating row numbers for duplicate rows in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column called 'ID'

ID column has 8 rows with values 100,100,100,200,200,300,300,300

I want to create a new column called 'Row_ID' which should look up at the ID column and give unique row number to each row where a duplicate id is found and restart the counter when a different value is found.

Example , for the above values of ID columns, the Row column should look like

```
1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3
```

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: It is a must to assume the result should be ordered by ID, right?

Comment: 1 This is for MSSQL. 2 Order by ID is right

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle Database

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS "ROW_ID"
FROM (
  SELECT 100 ID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 100 ID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 100 ID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 200 ID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 200 ID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 300 ID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 300 ID FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 300 ID FROM dual
)
```

Comment: This wroked "OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS "ROW_ID""